# equivalent monthly cost with multiple interest rates

Tags: calculation, interest

Is equivalent monthly cost equal to equivalent annual cost divided by 12?

Also, using the equivalent annual cost [HERE](http://financeformulas.net/Equivalent_Annual_Annuity.html), how would I change the formula for differing rates over the period of time.

Example:

6 years, PV = $15,000,

Interest Rates:

 Year 1 = 2% p.a.

 Year 2 = 3% p.a.

 Year 3 = 2% p.a.

 Year 4 = 2% p.a.

 Year 5 = 3.5% p.a.

 Year 6 = 3% p.a.

Would I take the average interest rate and use that? So:

 (2+3+2+2+3.5+3)/6 = 2.58%

Then divide 2.58%/12 = 0.215% for monthly

Thanks

Comment: You mention cost.  Are these *loans* which you have taken out, which you have taken out that have rates varying by year?

Comment: Its a similar style to the example on the page I linked, under the heading "Example of the Equivalent Annual Annuity Formula". However, the interest rate changes, my issue is how do i adjust the formula to account for changing interest rates.

Comment: OK, I see the "annuity" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) for the average interest rate in a time series.

```
gm = (1.02*1.03*1.02*1.02*1.035*1.03)^(1/6) - 1 = 0.02581541058
```

Comparing the interest over six years.

```
1.02*1.03*1.02*1.02*1.035*1.03 - 1 = 16.5239812 %

                    (1 + gm)^6 - 1 = 16.5239812 %
```

The equivalent annual annuity calculation (shown in the derivation) becomes

```
pv = (c 1.02^5 + c 1.03^4 + c 1.02^3 + 
      c 1.02^2 + c 1.035^1 + c 1.03^0)/(1 + gm)^6

∴ c = (pv (1 + gm)^6)/
        (1.02^5 + 1.03^4 + 1.02^3 + 1.02^2 + 1.035 + 1)

pv = $15000

∴ c = $2745.53
```

where `c` is the annuity cash flow.

For a monthly calculation the monthly rate is `(1 + r)^(1/12) - 1`

where `r` is the annual effective rate or the nominal annual rate compounded annually.

(The equivalent *annual* annuity calculation should use [the annual effective rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) or the nominal annual rate compounded annual, which is the same.  However, if you are calculating an equivalent *monthly* annuity the monthly rate can be taken as the nominal annual rate 'compounded monthly' divided by twelve.)

**Derivation & Check**

The equivalent annuity is based on the following summation, which shows the present value `pv` equal to the future value of the sum of the periodic cash flows (made at the beginning of each period) discounted to present value by division by `(1 + r)^n`.

[image]

By induction, the closed form is `pv = (c - c (1 + r)^-n)/r`

```
∴ c = (r pv)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n)
```

which matches the [formula provided](http://financeformulas.net/Equivalent_Annual_Annuity.html) by the OP.

Adding in webpage example figures.

```
pv = 100000
n = 4
r = 0.08

∴ c = (r pv)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 30192.08
```

Expressed as summation with geometric mean.

```
gm = (1.08*1.08*1.08*1.08)^(1/4) - 1 = 0.08

pv = (c 1.08^3 + c 1.08^2 + c 1.08^1 + c 1.08^0)/(1 + gm)^4 = 100000
```

So the summation expression checks out, although the example is a simplified case with a constant interest rate.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.02 * 1.03 * 1.02 * 1.02 * 1.035 * 1.03 = 1.165239
1.0258^6 = 1.165134
```

It's not the exact same, because of compounding.  It's really close, though.